# jQuery print JSON element whose key value equals name of li class

Tags: jquery, json

I retrieve a JSON object which contains the keys "options" and "message", whereas each options value has a corresponding li element in the document, for example [{"opt" : "12", "msg" : "red"}] exists a list element with class="12".

Now I want to do the following, when a user clicks the link inside on of the list elements, the value of the corresponding "msg" key should be displayed.

I have got it working up to the point that the message value of the first element of the JSON object is displayed on click, but it always displays message value of the first element in the JSON, no matter which link is clicked. I think has to do with the .attr(), but I am not sure.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code and the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/F7PuA/1/

HTML

```
 <ul id="list">
    <li class="12"> <a href="#12">Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="37"> <a href="#37">Option 2</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="message" style="display:none;"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#list li a").click(function () {

   var liclass = $("#list li").attr("class");

   var json = [{
       "opt": "12",
           "msg": "Red"
   }, {
       "opt": "37",
           "msg": "Green"
   }];

   $.each(json, function (key, value) {
       if (json[key].opt == liclass) {
           $(".message").empty().append(json[key].msg).fadeIn();
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: A better approach would be to use the data attribute to associate a unique numeric value to a DOM element.  Class attributes are intended for classifications.  ID could also work though it could get in the way of styling

Comment: Here is an approach that uses data attributes directly on the li elements: http://jsfiddle.net/m2jHt/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the example, unfortunately I can't change the server side code but I will keep it in mind for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the `li` in relation to the clicked `a` element, in this case you need to find the parent `li` of the clicked `a`.

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to do that

```
var liclass = $(this).closest('li').attr("class");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vr6w2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `liclass` initialization is always running on the *list* of `li` elements under `#list`, not the specific `li` that was clicked.  `attr` is returning the first `class` it finds.

Try:

```
var liclass = $(this).closest('li').attr("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `liClass` to point to the clicked hyperlink.

```
var liclass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
```

[Updated jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/F7PuA/2/)

**EDIT:** Perhaps you could just grab the number off of the `href` attr instead:

```
var liclass = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
```

[2nd jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/F7PuA/4/)